# how to hide index.php from url on litespeed server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, litespeed

url - `example.com/index.php`
want to hide `/index.php`
`htaccess` is enabled - some other rules work

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

doesn't work. `index.php` is still there
maybe because my server is `litespeed` and not `apache`
any help

Comment: Could you please show your full htaccess file that will give us better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - the above code is all I have inside `.htaccess` file

Comment: Ok so when you hit url `example.com/index.php` you want it to be like `example.com/` which should be served by index.pho in backend? Please confirm if my understanding is right here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - yes, that's it - but without ending slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, please try following.

Use either code:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]
```

OR with `THE_REQUEST` variable try:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \sindex\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot. could you give me some explanation, pls. Or a reference page where I could understand this code

Comment: @qadenza, IMHO you could try updated code once, this should work for you too.

Comment: @qadenza, For reference I usually prefer documentation link https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ which is having detailed level of knowledge, please do let me know in case of any queries here, cheers.

Comment: now it doesn't work. Your previous code works

Comment: @qadenza, sure, I have added both for me now, since both worked for me, cheers.